# How meaningful is the notion of 'now' here on Earth?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, observers, estimation

So special relativity and the lack of a now moment is causing me a bit of grief.

My friends and families notion of "now" doesn't ever line up with mine;  but how much of a difference does this make?  How big are the differences between my "now" and other people's "now"?  Is there any way to estimate this?

Comment: Have you estimated the size of the discrepancies   that are troubling you?

Comment: Also:  Prior to learning about relativity, were you unaware that different people have different perceptions, depending on things like which way they happen to be facing?

Comment: Well, the idea that you're facing a different direction does not impede on your brain state. But I gather that the differences are very very small and I think have no impact on another observers brain state.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding relativity here?

Comment: You don't think your brain state is affected by what you can see?

Comment: No not like that obviously your brain is affected by what it can see. but I mean my description would have impacts on things like identity right?  I'm asking a question that's causing me grief I promise I'm not stupid. I just want to know how much relativity changes things on earth if at all

Comment: The question is not about physics, but about human perception. It is better asked in [Philosophy community](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The physics aspect of my question I think crosscuts the philosophy aspect. I would like some numerical advice etc regarding how much time on earth varies between observers

Comment: If not numerical a qualitative description of how little time changes on earth between observers

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really a question about [Philosophy.SE], not physics.

Comment: Before we close it then can someone give a quick answer. Just summarising I'll be off happily thanks

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your most recent comment before I voted to close.  I retracted my close vote and instead I edited your question to ask something that you mentioned in the comments and which *is* answerable on this stack (I think.)  Feel free to revert your question if you think I've changed it too much.

Comment: It's a standard exercise to check that two people passing on the street at normal everyday speeds can disagree by several weeks about the timing of events in the galaxy Andromeda.  (So one says "we last met about a week after Andromeda exploded" while the other says "No, it was a week **before** ") But it's hard (for me at least) to see any circumstance in which this would cause me a problem.

Comment: Time runs differently in different gravity fields, including those accessible here on Earth. It is a not-so-difficult experiment to demonstrate that two atomic clocks will show different times after one has been driven up a mountain and left for a while...

Comment: One last comment:   When you and I pass each other on the street, one going east and one going west, we have different notions of what's happening "now".  (For events on earth, these differences are tiny; for events far away the differences can be quite large.)  We also have (very) different notions of what's happening "straight ahead".   These differences are huge, even for events here on earth.  Does the latter cause you grief?

Comment: Are u trying to wind me up. It was a genuine question man. Ye I guess it does its crazy to think about

Comment: But from what I've gathered on Earth the differences are tiny they have no real influence on our notion of now

Comment: Nobody is trying to "wind you up".  I hoped you'd be willing to help clarify exactly what it is that's troubling you.  The ambiguity about "now" and the ambiguity about "straight ahead" are **exactly** the same kind of ambiguity; they both result from the fact that you and I use different reference frames to describe the same universe.  A first step toward understanding why one troubles you is to determine whether the other troubles you equally, and if not, what you see as the important difference between them.

Comment: Sorry I think I read your comment wrong. Ye so its mainly the notion of another observers experience. If there's no now what is say my friend experiencing when we hang out does it line up with my experience of them.

Comment: I still don't understand what difference you are seeing between "If my friend use the word NOW differently, then I can't know what he's experiencing" and "If my friend and I use the word AHEAD differently, then I can't know what he's experiencing".   In both cases, you are using different language to describe the same universe, and in each case you both know how to translate back and forth between one language and the other.   Why are you perceiving one of these situations as more troublesome than the other?

Comment: So, if you're moving away from me real quickly like the 0.5c your hypersurface of simultaneity crosscuts my past. Therefore in your notion of the universe my present moment from my perspective doesn't line up with the me in your version of now. This isn't simply a matter of perspective there is literally a temporal version of me with a physically different set of mental experiences from your perspective than in my own perspective.

Comment: Are you saying it's possible to translate between our perspectives and I am overcomplicating this and misunderstanding the implications? Should I just go and learn the maths?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to translate between your perspectives.  The dictionary is called a Lorentz transformation.  It really is no different from the sort of translation you do when you are facing me, I tell you that the restaurant is "straight ahead", and you figure  out that therefore the restaurant is directly behind you.  If you are comfortable sharing an email address, I will send you some notes that I believe will help a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142528/discussion-between-ecologitefacies-and-willo).

Comment: So I've read up a bit but I'm not sure if my assessment where different temporal iterations in each reference frame was a mischaracterisation. I gather that as a changing plane of simultaneity has no impacts on spatially separate events the answer is I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### scale of relativistic effects

To get a sense of scale, the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) appears in many S.R. equations and gives the general scale of relativistic effects.
$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$$

If the relative velocity between two reference frames, $v$, is zero, then $\gamma=1$.  An observer moving 60% the speed of light ($0.6c \approx 1.8\times10^8$ m/s) has $\gamma=1.25$, causing among other things that observer's clock to run about 25% slower compared to yours.

For speeds commonly achieved by people on Earth, relativistic effects are negligible.  A person moving at the speed of sound, $v_s = 343$ m/s, has $\gamma = 1.000\,000\,000\,000\,65$.  Relativistic effects come in at the parts-per-quintillion level.

### different "now"

Your question about a local sense of "now" is related to surfaces of simultaneity.  A surface of simultaneity is effectively all of the points in spacetime that one observer would assign the same time coordinate.  Everything that happens at the same time.  Because of the [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity), two observers won't agree on how to slice up spacetime into these surfaces of simultaneity.  So how different is your "now" compared to another person's?

The [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) allow us to determine the coordinates that another observer would measure $(\bar{t}, \bar{x})$ for an event based on what you measured $(t, x)$.  The time transformation looks like this:

$$\bar{t} = \gamma \left( t - \frac{v}{c^2}x\right).$$

Let's say we both measure two events, $A$ and $B$, while I am moving $0.6 c$ relative to you.  As I pass you, two firecrackers go off.  One occurs at $t_A = 0$, $x_A = 0$, right where we are.  According to you the other occurs at the same time but $100$ m away $t_B = 0$, $x_B = 100$ m.

Plugging in the coordinates for event $A$, I should observe it at
$$\bar{t}_A = \gamma \left( 0 - \frac{v}{c^2}\cdot 0 \right) = 0,$$
right where we are.  For event $B$, I observe
$$\bar{t}_B = 1.25\left( 0 - \frac{0.6 c}{c^2}\cdot 100\,\mathrm{m} \right) = -75\,\mathrm{m}/c\approx -2.5\times 10^{-7}\mathrm{s}.$$
According to my local conception of now, firecracker $B$ explodes 0.25 micro-seconds before firecracker $A$.  Would I notice?

This is of course assuming I'm traveling 60% the speed of light!  If I were traveling at the speed of sound, the difference would be even harder to notice: about $4\times 10^{-13}$ s or $0.0004$ nano-seconds.

Larger distances would have bigger discrepancies in simultaneity. But despite our ability to receive information from across the globe, our local perception is likely limited to a few kilometers at most.  There's basically no way you would ever notice differences in "now" compared to your friends or family.

The negligible nature of relativity in everyday life is exactly why nobody figured it out sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about 'Here on Earth', and here on Earth there is a specific circumstance that I will get to further on in this answer.

For comparison let me first state the standard case where relativity of simultaneity manifests itself:

Let there be a fleet of spaceships, arranged in a linear formation. The ships of the fleet maintain synchronized fleet time using Einstein synchronization convention. Let's call that the red fleet.

Let there be a second fleet of spaceships, arranged in a linear formation co-linear with the red fleet, but with a velocity relative to the red fleet. Let's call that the green fleet. The green fleet maintains a synchronized fleet time using Einstein synchronization convention.

As we know, under those circumstances the red fleet and the green fleet don't have the same simultaneity. Both are self-consistent simultaneities, and they don't coincide.

**On Earth**

Here on Earth there are many centers dedicated to time-keeping. These centers are not distributed evenly over the Earth, of course, but there is a sufficient number of them to maintain a global synchronized Earth time.

Each of those centers has multiple atomic clocks running, and they are continuously exchanging timing signals with other centers, to verify consistency.

The procedures for using those timing signals takes transmission delay into account.

For simplicity let's suppose there are 4 centers located at even intervals along the Equator, and timing signals are transmitted as radio signal.

[image: Schematic representation of the Sagnac effect]

In the animated gif the grey dots represent the 4 centers for time keeping. There are two trains of timing signals, represented with the red dots and blue dots respectively. From here on I will refer to the radio signals as 'the red signals' and 'the blue signals'.

In the animation the velocity of the red dots and blue dots is the same; the counter-propagating dots keep crossing each other at the same four points. This represents a property of the counter-propagating radio signals. As a matter of principle: at each point in the space the speed of radio signals is the same in both directions. More generally: everywhere in space the propagation speed of electromagnetic waves is the same in all directions.

**Loop topology**

The important feature here is that the timing signals are going round in a loop. In effect the red signals and blue signals are propagating in a space that loops back onto itself.

The fact that this particular space *loops back onto itself* gives rise to something that is not present in the thought demonstrations of the two fleets of spaceships that are each in *linear formation*.

In the animation, consider the four grey dots (that represent time keeping centers.)

The procedure here is to arrange the timing of the pulses such that the time pulses are equally spaced.

As measured by the time keeping centers: the time it takes a red signals to propagate from one center to the next is longer than the time it takes for a blue signal to propagate from one center to the next.

The amount of difference in time of propagation is proportional to the angular velocity of the Earth. That is: it is possible to infer the rotation rate of the Earth from that difference in time of propagation between the two counter-propagating trains of timing pulses.

Incidentally, this effect is the operating principle of a particular type of angular velocity measuring device: a ring laser interferometer. The underlying effect is named [Sagnac effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect)

The combined efforts of the time keeping centers results in a single global Earth time.

The same goes for the GPS system: throughout the entire system a single time is used.

So that is the specific circumstance here on Earth that I started this answer with: here on Earth we have the option to make timing signals to *go around in a loop*.

(It isn't necessarily the case that the procedures actually implement that. It is not *necessary* to infer the rotation rate from observing the time signals. Undoubtedly it is more effecient to take the Earth rotation rate as a given, and to take the specific delay effect arising from that into account when accounting for the total transmission delay.)

For more information I recommend the following article by Olaf Wucknitz, 2007: '[Sagnac effect, twin paradox and space-time topology — Time and length in rotating systems and closed Minkowski space-times](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0403111)'.

In my opinion the discussion by Olaf Wucknitz is way ahead of anyone else.

I cannot emphasize enough the striking contrast:
In newtonian space&time closing a loop does not make a difference. In Minkowski spacetime closing a loop has profound ramifications.